# Call function of a class object from ajax request in Javascript doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I do an ajax request with jquery. And I have a class which I named as "Service". I create an instance of this class firstly. Then I call getPage function. It works but it doesnt call onSuccessFunction function of callback object. Why? Where am I missing?

**Note:** If I call the onSuccessFunction from out of ajax request, it works.

**service.js:**

```
class Service 
    {

        constructor(serviceUrl)
        {
            this.serviceUrl = serviceUrl;
        } 

        getPage(bookId, pageNumber, query, callback)
        {
            console.log("C1");
            this.getResponse("GET", "reader/book/" + bookId + "/page/" + pageNumber + "/query/" + query, "", callback);
        }

        getResponse(type, path, parameters, callback)
        {
            var data = "";
            if(type == 'POST')
            {
                data = parameters.toString();
            }

            $.ajax({
                type: type,
                async: false,
                url: this.serviceUrl + "/" + path,
                data:data,
                success: function(result)
                {
                    callback.onSuccessFunction(result);
                },
                error: function(xhr) 
                {
                    callback.onErrorFunction(xhr.message);
                },
            });
        }

    }
```

**callback.js:**

```
class CallBack 
{
    constructor(onSuccessFunction, onErrorFunction) 
    {
        this.onSuccessFunction = onSuccessFunction;
        this.onErrorFunction = onErrorFunction;
    }

}
```

**index.html**

```
var callback = new CallBack(onPageCallBackSuccess, onPageCallBackError);
service.getPage('<%= bookId %>', newPageNumber, query, callback);
```

Comment: `url: this.serviceUrl + "/" + path,` Where is `serviceUrl` variable in your class?

Comment: Does it matter? It is not related with serviceUrl. Please read note.

Comment: yes it matters. Are you getting any error function on console?

Comment: No. I am not...

Comment: are you getting any error from error function of ajax?

Comment: No. I am not...

Comment: are you able to call ajax function?

Comment: Yes I'm able...

Comment: Can you show us the code where you're trying to use your `Service` object?

Comment: I updated my question by your asking

Comment: no one to help?